# Create a n x m array of polynomials using a (n x 1) data through Numpy/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I created an array using the following:

```
 = np.random.normal(0,1,50), which gave me
array([ 1.92024714, -0.19882742, -0.26836024,  0.32805879, -0.32085809,
       -0.23569939,  0.22310599,  0.5483915 , -0.13106083, -1.03798811,
        0.4586899 , -1.7378367 , -0.49868295,  1.58943447,  0.92153814,
        0.38894787, -1.26605208,  0.44308314,  1.10222734,  0.40031394,
       -1.2126154 ,  0.26871733, -0.85161259,  0.15853002, -0.18531145,
       -0.18069696,  0.19121711,  0.16586507,  0.43668293,  0.38395065,
       -1.02418998,  0.10464186, -0.02777545, -0.30571787,  1.0690931 ,
       -0.67266002,  2.00256049, -0.05156432, -1.03735733,  0.27650841,
       -0.53300549, -0.4301668 ,  1.01371008, -0.70780846,  0.11577668,
        0.19328765, -0.72971236,  1.61804424, -0.69770352, -1.33161613])
```

For each element of this array how can I do the following to give me a 50x3 matrix something like this – ANY SUGGESTIONS ?

```
1^1     1^2     1^3
2^1     2^2     2^3
3^1     3^2     3^3
.
.
50^1     50^2     50^3
```

i.e. the numbers in 50x1 array above would look this in an 50 x 3 array

```
1.92024714     3.68734907867818      7.08062152251341
-0.19882742    0.03953234294385     -0.00786011375408 
-0.26836024     0.07201721841285     -0.01932655801740
. 
.
.
.
.
-1.33161613     1.77320151767618     -2.36122374267808
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're describing here is called a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).  `numpy` has this built in (and more performant than broadcasting on large matrices)

The first column of a Vandermonde matrix is always `1`, so you can filter that out if you wish.

---

```
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 50)

np.vander(a, 4, increasing=True)[:, 1:]
```

```
array([[ 4.21022633e-01,  1.77260058e-01,  7.46304963e-02],   
       [-9.37208666e-02,  8.78360084e-03, -8.23206683e-04],   
                          ...   
       [-9.02260087e-01,  8.14073265e-01, -7.34505815e-01],   
       [ 1.21125200e+00,  1.46713140e+00,  1.77706584e+00]])
```

---

Just for a bit of validation:

```
>>> np.isclose(np.vander(a, 4, increasing=True)[:, 1:], a[:, None]**np.arange(1, 4)).all()
True
```

---

On large matricies, `vander` beats broadcasting:

```
a = np.random.normal(0, 1, 10_000)

In [99]: %timeit np.vander(a, 100, increasing=True)[:, 1:]
8.37 ms ± 97 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [100]: %timeit a[:, None]**np.arange(1, 100)
51.4 ms ± 904 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

If you don't want a strictly increasing matrix, this becomes far less useful, and will calculate unnecessary powers, in which case you should fall back to the broadcasted solution.

Comment: On my machine `vander` beats the broadcasting solution on smaller matrices with the same size as the OP, due to the slowness of `**` operation.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

```
np.column_stack((a, a**2, a**3))
```

---

```
array([[ 1.92024714e+00,  3.68734908e+00,  7.08062152e+00],
       [-1.98827420e-01,  3.95323429e-02, -7.86011375e-03],
              ...      ,        ...     ,       ...
       [-6.97703520e-01,  4.86790202e-01, -3.39635237e-01],
       [-1.33161613e+00,  1.77320152e+00, -2.36122374e+00]])
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way leveraging [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a = np.random.normal(0,1,50)

out = a[:,None]**np.arange(1,4)

print(out.shape)
# (50, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

All, many thanks for your responses. I'm a beginner at Python and it's great to see three different ways to address this problem. I read and educated myself about all three.

Thanks again !!